# Intel XDK include latest cordova script

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, intel-xdk

In a typical app script built with intel XDK , there is something like :

```
<script src="intelxdk.js"></script>
```

Actually the JS file doesnt exist on local disk , but it is automatically added to the package once you build your app ( added from server ) , the question is , if I include the cordova script , will Intel automatically add the latest cordova version to my app  , if not , how can i manage this and add my own version ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, XDK will automatically include the appropriate cordova.js file. You will just need to add the script tag in your code.

Comment: what about plugins , will it be included automatically ? because i used a geolocation function without adding any plugin , and it worked !

Comment: In the "standard" builds all the core Cordova 2.9 plugins are automatically added. In the new beta Cordova builds you must specify which plugins are added using an intelxdk.config.xml file. That build system uses Cordova 3.3 (at the time this was written).

Comment: @xmnboy but i havent added any plugins and the config.xml and the geolocation works well !

Comment: @ProllyGeek -- yes, the geolocation stuff is built into many of the webviews so you don't need to include a Cordova plugin to get to geo; the geo behavior varies slightly over the platforms, but the API is consistent. I've just finished up an app that demonstrates the geo and a few other APIs located here: https://github.com/xmnboy/hello-cordova. This will eventually end up as an XDK sample.